# Loading a single record with Ember 2.0 and Ember Data 2.0

Tags: ember.js, record, http-get

I've come unstuck when trying to fetch a single record using Ember Data 2.

The server is designed to respond to a GET request  like this:

`GET http://server/api/results/1`

with this as a result:

```
{
   "results" : [
     {
        "id": 1,
        "catname": "Category 1",
     }
   ]
}
```

The Ember route code looks like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
        return this.store.find('game',12);
   }
});
```

The problem is that there doesn't appear to be a network request going out (a previous findAll fetch has worked, so I don't think it's the adapter), and there is an error I have not been able to find informaiton on:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property'crossDomain' of undefined

Does anyone have any idea what this could be, of hint at how I might track this down?

Comment: Is your API server on the same domain as your frontend client? Does `GET http://server/api/results/1` response have HTTP header that allows for CORS? What'd be URL for `this.store.find('game',12);`? `GET http://server/api/games/12`?

Comment: The API server is in a different domain, but the findAll request to a different target on the same server works.

Comment: What does your adapter look like? `findAll` by default, pluralizes your query. I.e. if you `findAll('game', 12)` you will hit `api/v1/games` instead of `game`.  You can edit your adapter to control how your queries are handled, however.

Comment: The adapter is just the default methods... The successful Ali call uses pluralisation, but this one fails pluralised or not. Looking at the network trace there doesn't wven appear to be an attempt to hit the app for this findRecord, and the Ali server certainly gives no indication of a hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1.13 new methods was [introduced](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_new-adapter-hooks-for-better-caching). You should use `findRecord` instead of `find`.
Also, ember expects following response when fetching a single object:

```
{
   "result" : 
     {
        "id": 1,
        "catname": "Category 1",
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I originally tried findRecord and then started looking for answers, moving to find. Unfortunately moving back to this didn't change the outcome, so I must be missing something somewhere else...